# Objects comunication with parent in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, communication, parent

Now, I have been looking for the answer to this for a while, but Google and all my power seems to fail me.

I got this Class. (MyWorld).
Within MyWorld I have an Array of objects

```
GameUnit m_MyUnits[] = new GameUnit[maxUnits];
```

Right now m_MyUnits are filled up with GameUnits and subclasses here off, and the are walking around the screen happy as cheesecake.
I have even written my own little collision detection for each of them, so they won’t bump into each other.

And all works fine, BUT!
For my collision detection to work I have chosen the slowest of ways (and most memory requiring I think)

In MyWorld I first loop trough each GameUnit and gets its X and Y position for an array 
private int[][] Positions = new int[2][maxUnits]);

I then loop trough each and every GameUnit and assigns this array to it. (GameUnit has its own array called Positions for this)

Now, while this works, I can’t help but think that this is stupid like …. Well, I won’t use those words here.

Is there a way for GameUnit to Call the Positions in MyWorld, or even better, for the game unit to call the Array m_MyUnits[].getX() and m_MyUnits[].getY() in MyWorld
Some thing like this (I use Parent to refer to MyWorld from the GameUnit)

```
For(int i = 0;i < Parent.maxUnits;i++) {
  int targetX = Parent. m_MyUnits[i].getX();
  int targetY = Parent. m_MyUnits[i].getX();
  //Do some thing like collition detection with the data.
}
```

Is this possible, or?

Yours JavaApprentis.

Comment: do you have a reference to the variable instance of `MyWorld` or are all the things you want to get `static`? Also this level of dependency might indicate that your design is flawed.

Comment: Yea it is flawed… or I guess so?
If you ask weather or not I have passed any information of MyWorld to the instances of GameUnit then no.
I haven’t! Its kind of what I’d like to do I guess. But I am not sure.
If Id like to do this, then how do I do that?
the constructor of GameUnit is(int,int,double) what to add?
and what to pass?

Comment: Then you can do what @ErnestFriedmanHill suggests and add a `MyWorld` argument to your constructor.

Comment: a couple other hints -- almost _nobody_ in the Java world uses Hungarian notation ("m_XXXX").  It has become idiomatic to avoid that in Java programs.  Also it is idiomatic (and just good design) to not provide direct field access like you have done with m_MyUnits, but to make it private and provide a public getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a `GameUnit`, you could pass the `MyWorld` as a constructor argument. The `GameUnit` constructor could then store the `MyWorld` object in a member variable. Then when it needed to do collsion detection, it could ask the `MyWorld` for a list of potential partners by calling a method on that object.

In `GameUnit`:

```
private MyWorld myWorld;

public GameUnit(int,int,double, MyWorld m) {
    myWorld = m;
}
```

And then in `MyWorld`, when you make a `GameUnit`:

```
new GameUnit(1, 2, 1.0, this);
```

Then in all the methods of `GameUnit`, you have the `MyWorld` object in `myWorld` available for use.

Comment: hay thanks, but. as i answerd twain before:
Id like to do this, but how do I do that? the constructor of GameUnit is(int,int,double) what to add? and what to pass? and what to call?

Comment: Thanks man, this saved me (just took off 80% of the RAM i used when running the program. thx.)

Answer (score 0):

Sort of
Add a World property of type MyWorld to GameUnit.
Change GameUnit's constructor to accept World as an argument and set World to it.

Add GetX and GetY methods to MyWorld, that wrap up m_MyUnits[i].getX() and getY with the index in the array as an argument.

to give something like

```
For(int i = 0;i < World.maxUnits;i++) {
  int targetX = World. getX(i);
  int targetY = World. getY(i);
  //Do some thing like collition detection with the data.
}
```

Saying that I think I'd invert this and do something like

```
If (World.Collide(this))
{
  // Die messily.
}
```